# Can't find libxml XAMPP

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xampp

I'm setting up XMPPFramework manually.

I've following [this Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091767/up-to-date-instructions-on-how-to-install-xmppframework-manually/30543948#30543948). All working well excepting

> 'libxml' not found

Can't find solution.

Here is screenshot of error:

[image]

Related Stack Question, but can't get answer:

- [#import <libxml/tree.h> file not found after xcode 6.1 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857531/import-libxml-tree-h-file-not-found-after-xcode-6-1-update)
- [libxml/tree.h no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428847/libxml-tree-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Just to clarify. Is it `libxml` or `libxml2` ?

Comment: It's libxml. Please see screenshot.

Comment: Please have a look at this thread  https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/591