# Unable to build XMPPframework

Tags: ios, xcode, xmppframework

I want to build [xmppframework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) using XCode. I'm a newbie in ios development. I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091767/up-to-date-instructions-on-how-to-install-xmppframework-manually/30543948#30543948) but couldn't build it. I couldnt get any clear steps to build it elsewhere as well. Can someone help me in building it or show some pointers from where i can start. I've copied Cocoalumberjack, cocoaAsyncSocket framework to the project and added KissXML and added libxml2 path in header and it library.

I'm getting the below error:

error: /Users/karsomas/eRDK/ios_dev/xmppClient/XMPPFramework/Vendor/CocoaLumberjack/Extensions/README.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: remove README.txt file from given location(as well as from your project - you may see it red coloured), just remove it will make it build

Comment: Also, make sure that all the build settings for dependecies -> kissXML,lumberjack,asycSocket etc are  properly added

Comment: Also, make sure that even after building, you will not now be able to use gtalk/hangout(we were using this before, but not googles stopped giving that service) for using XMPP, you must have to your own XMPP server running

Comment: I Just cloned those repos and dragged them from finder into my project. I don't know what other settings that I need to set. If possible can you please elaborate them or share a link which I can follow.

Comment: follow the steps provided here : https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS

Comment: And link for steps of adding other dependencies are provided in above link itself, wherever it is written that add "XYZ" dependency, go to given dependency's github page(links already provided) and follow the steps(specifically for kissXML, when i have done first time, i missed that)

Comment: I followed all the steps, now I'm getting error at @ import KissXML;  saying "use of @ import when modules are disabled" and lots of error related to that.